# Eclipse setup for electronics

Tags: discussion

I'm unsure if the EE stack exchange or stack overflow is the best place to ask about help with setting up a specific feature in eclipse IDE. Its programming (debugging) but I'm using features that most programmers won't use, as its for interfacing electronics so I doubt stack overflow will be helpful as it likely won't be seen by those who know what I'm talking about. Where would be recommended to post this question? (oh and I assume this is the sort of thing to ask on meta)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If it's a question related to debugging an embedded / microcontroller system I would say it's on topic here and go for it. Of course keep it well defined and scoped as you would on any SE site but otherwise I can't see a problem.